# Gaussian random walk of drifting electrons in $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ limit

Tags: diffusion, displacement

Consider the movement of electrons due to diffusion in a liquid as described by the solution of the diffusion equation

$$\phi(\vec x, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(4\pi t)^3 D_xD_yDz}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4 D_xt}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{4 D_yt}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4 D_zt}\right),$$

where $D_i$ are the diffusion constants we assume that the whole process takes place at the origin of the coordinate system.
I want to simulate the process of diffusion by dividing the time into small steps $\Delta t$. At each step, the displacements $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$ are calculated by inserting $\Delta t$ into the corresponding parts of the product of Gaussians in $\phi(\vec x, t)$.

At the same time, an electric field pointing in the $z$ direction is applied to the system. It leads to a movement of the electrons with a constant drift velocity of $v_D$. So, in addition to the diffusion displacement of $\Delta z$, a constant distance of $v_D\cdot\Delta t$ has to be added in each time step.

Physically, the influence of the drift velocity is larger than the one of the diffusion. However, if we choose very small time steps ($\Delta t \rightarrow 0$), the standard deviation of the diffusion $\sqrt{2D_i \Delta t}$ decreases less fast than $v_D \cdot t$ due to the square root, so the influences of the two processes switch their roles.

Therefore, I think this model does not hold for such small time steps. Is there a constriction which has to be considered? Does this approach work at all or is there maybe a better one to use instead?